# Getting familiar with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Iam not able to get familiar with XAMPP interface on Windows7 (Only prior experiencxe is with HTML,C,C++).
How to proceed to begin development work in PHP and MySQL and test developed contents using Apache Server.
Please help to understand its working flow.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sumit, if you **edit** or expand your post due to a question it would be nice to **say this** somehow in your post. OK, you are using Win7, and I'd guess from your other posts its Win7 **x64** right?

Comment: Hi Rubber...after the fisrt comment i realised its one of the important thing i missed for others to answer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find a good PHP book or tutorial to learn PHP.  There are plenty out there, just Google or visit the [PHP homepage](http://www.php.net/).

As you follow the book or tutorial, save your .php files in the XAMPP `htdocs` folder.  This will let you view your results using the XAMPP web server.  For example, if you write a PHP script called `test.php` and save it in the `htdocs` folder, you can access it on your local XAMPP server via http://localhost/test.php.

XAMPP includes phpMyAdmin, which lets you manage the included MySQL database.  You can learn more about phpMyAdmin [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

Be sure to read the XAMPP documentation so that you know how to start up Apache and MySQL and access phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is only a service that provides a webserver, server side language (PHP), database and interface to connect to said interface. Once it is installed you are good to go, all you need to do is turn on Apache, then MySQL. All the rest of the installation requirements should be done automatically upon installation.

Maybe it is better to explain your particular issue...

Answer (score 0):

I was beginning from Denwer. It was very easy to begin with him. He includes php, mysql, apache.

> http://www.denwer.ru

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the Apache server for php and the MySQL server for MySQL :D. You can run it by starting the XAMPP Control and than run them. Now you can go to the localhost http://localhost/
There are some instructions.

I hope it is useful.

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need XAMPP? Sumit, I also have Win7/x64 on one machine, where I installed

- [Apache 2.2.16](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) for **32bit** Windows
- [PHP 5.3.2](http://windows.php.net/download/) (x32 Windows **VC6** install binary)
- [Perl 5.12.1 32bit](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) x86 from Activestate
- [MySQL 5.1 32bit](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) x86 Windows installer)

I installed **all-32-bit** stuff (even if on 64bit Windows) because that **guarantees** you a much simpler life. You can handle or maintain every component individually, for including PHP or Perl into Apache, you just change a line or two in the Apache config file. **There's no magic at all** with all these programs. Install them by yourself and **learn a lot** in the process.